# XML parser Unsuccessful

Tags: xml

D2L_XML4 parser is unsuccessfully trying to update a user with
the following XML. Assuming the  value is correct,it keeps failing. Can anybody explain this please...

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<enterprise>
<person recstatus="1">
<sourcedid>
<id>D2L0001</id>
</sourcedid>

<userid password="MyPassword">Johnny.Test</userid>
<name>

<n>
<family>Test, Jr.</family>
<given>Johnny</given>
</n>

</name>
<email>Johnny.Test@d2l.ca</email>
<extension>

<role roletype="Sample Role">
<status>1<status>
</role>
</extension>
</person>
</enterprise>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<status>1<status>
          ^
          |
      Missing /
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot ! Missed my eyes. Thanks Again!